# changed df -h output format after yum update in rhel6.5

Tags: patch, lvm

changed `df -h` output after `yum update` (after patching). Anybpdy help on this ?
Anybody knows the reason behind this ?

`df -h` output **before** `yum update` (rhel patching) :

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   37G  9.1G   27G  26% /
tmpfs                          20G   72K   20G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                     485M   40M  421M   9% /boot
10.51.20.10:/SAPPCK            60G  5.7G   54G  10% /sapck
PJ3SMB:/export/sapmnt        1008M   33M  924M   4% /sapmnt
PJ3SMB:/export/usr/sap        4.0G  136M  3.7G   4% /usr/sap
PJ3SMB:/export/home/pj3adm   1008M   33M  924M   4% /home/pj3adm
PJ3SMB:/export/etc/samba/sap 1008M   33M  924M   4% /etc/samba/sap
PJ3SMB:/export/sapmnt/PJ3     4.0G  1.9G  1.9G  50% /sapmnt/PJ3
PJ3SMB:/export/usr/sap/PJ3    2.0G  606M  1.3G  32% /usr/sap/PJ3
```

`df -h` output **after** `yum update` (rhel patching)

```
                     6.0G  1.2G  4.5G  21% /db2/db2dr1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-dr1_db2dr1
                      4.0G  176M  3.6G   5% /db2/DR1/db2dr1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-log_dir
                       40G   29G  8.5G  78% /db2/DR1/log_dir
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-log_archive
                       40G   38G   19M 100% /db2/DR1/log_archive
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-log_retrieve
                       15G  166M   14G   2% /db2/DR1/log_retrieve
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-db2dump
                      5.0G  768M  4.0G  17% /db2/DR1/db2dump
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-sapdata1
                      133G   49G   78G  39% /db2/DR1/sapdata1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-sapdata2
                      133G   49G   78G  39% /db2/DR1/sapdata2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-sapdata3
                      133G   49G   78G  39% /db2/DR1/sapdata3
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-sapdata4
                      133G   49G   78G  39% /db2/DR1/sapdata4
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-saptemp1
                       69G  180M   66G   1% /db2/DR1/saptemp1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-backup
                      493G  320G  148G  69% /backup
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-dr1adm
                     1008M   49M  908M   6% /home/dr1adm
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-sap
                      4.0G  3.6G  192M  95% /usr/sap
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-sap_dr1
                      2.0G  413M  1.5G  22% /usr/sap/DR1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-sap_hostctrl
                      2.0G  157M  1.8G   9% /usr/sap/hostctrl
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-sapmnt
                     1008M   34M  924M   4% /sapmnt
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-sapmnt_dr1
                      6.0G  757M  4.9G  14% /sapmnt/DR1
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-samba_sap
                     1008M   34M  924M   4% /etc/samba/sap
/dev/mapper/VolGroup02-temp
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `df -P`:        **-P, --portability Use the POSIX output format**

Answer (score 0):

You had different sets of filesystems mounted, i.e. you effectively had different inputs for `df`. The fact that the output is different is not due to a change in `df`, but to a change in its inputs.

When the length of the volume paths is too long to fit in the first column, `df` moves to the next line after printing it, before printing the sizes and mount point.

To avoid this behavior and get one line per volume, pass the `-P` option. You might get columns that aren't aligned but you'll get a single line per volume.